# Is there any way to convert an AngularJS web application to a mobile application?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm new to AngularJS. Is there any way to convert a whole AngularJS application to a mobile native App (Android and iOS) or AngularJS itself. Is there a way to create a mobile app?

I have referred the [xdk](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-xdk) and [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/products/#desktop-app-section).

Comment: It's possible with framework, for instance nativescript

Comment: Ram, please check my answer. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) or [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/). The use of cross platform libs is very comfortable while you are able to create different native apps by using one sourcecode. With phonegap/cordova you need node.js.

These are the default CLI commands for [setup your application](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/). You should create a new hybrid app by using the following commands. You could migrate your AngularJS application by copy-past your files into the new app directory.

Install cordova via NPM

```
npm install -g cordova.
```

Create your app (You could put your AngularJS App in your app directory and make it work)

```
cordova create <path>
```

Add a platform e.g. iOS or Android (The following command need to be run in the app `<path>` directory `cordova create <path>` has been configured.

```
 cordova platform add android --save
```

Run your app in emulator

```
cordova run android
```

Build a native App like:

```
cordova build android
```

Comment: Hi lin,  When run npm install -g cordova. on git getting error "npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead".

Comment: Thanks lin, I have integrated that things when i run the cordova platform add android --save Getting Following error  "$ cordova platform add android --save
Error: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project." i have googled also. i have created empty folder for android  and copy pasted all the AngularJS App to myapp(android). and i run that command.

Comment: @Ram run `cordova platform add android --save` in your directory where you created your project `cordova create <path>`...

Comment: i have copied all my angular js files to androidappfolder (which is located in C:\xampp\htdocs\newapp\androidappfolder) . "team-1@userMINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/newapp/androidapp"  when i run this cmd "$ cordova platform add android --save  Error showing 
"Error: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.
"

Comment: please join in chat

Comment: @Ram still no success?!

Comment: after  running this cmd creating cordova platform add android --save . is not working.where i want to put angular js code to android

Comment: sorry for late reply. there?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that worked for me in android :
 1. Create a plain native app in android.
 2. Keep the angular app in resources folder.
 3. Call the app in webview.

Similar solution may be possible in ios also, I haven't tried yet.

Comment: Weljea, that's exactly what `cordova`does under the hood :)